# Add a row to Sqlite crashes if use getResources.getString() to add string value

Tags: android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm  trying to add a row to Sqlite. At the beggining I was adding the row like this : (worked)

```
sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Family VALUES (" + index_family + ",'" + R.string.f1_pavimentos + "','" + (R.string.f0_descripcionPropamsa + "','" + R.drawable.color_pavimento + "');");
```

But was not good idea, beacause it only saves de id of the string, and I want the value. So I decided to do:

```
sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Family VALUES (" + index_family + ",'" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.f1_pavimentos )+ "','" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.f0_descripcionPropamsa )+ "','" + R.drawable.color_pavimento + "');");
```

adding the `getResources.getString()` but it crashes sending me this error:

```
07-16 10:42:26.200    1746-1746/com.propamsa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.propamsa, PID: 1746
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.propamsa/com.propamsa.listas.FamilyList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
            at com.propamsa.basededatos.ProductDBHandler.insertInformation(ProductDBHandler.java:183)
            at com.propamsa.basededatos.ProductDBHandler.onCreate(ProductDBHandler.java:57)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
            at com.propamsa.basededatos.ProductDBHandler.getAllFamiliesCursor(ProductDBHandler.java:109)
            at com.propamsa.listas.FamilyList.onCreate(FamilyList.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
```

And can see that is caused by `NullPointer`, but the string exist and is well spelled.

How can I save the string of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, your **context** is null.
Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `context`

Comment: mmm.. I not able to get `getApplicationContext()` . it gives me a error. The class is :  `ProductDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: If it's inside a Fragment, then try using `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`, instead. Or you could pass the Context as a parameter for your database methods.

Comment: Sorry. I found the problem. I was attaching the recived context in the wrong site., but your answer was the clue ;)